# Calculating area between two plots in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to find area formed between a barplot and a curve/normal plot in R. I've used ggplot2 package for all plotting purposes and used gglocator to identify the coordinates. But I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate area between the curves. The barplot will remain constant but the curve will change (as it is each row of a df).

Here's a reproducible code similar to my problem:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggmap)

x1 <- seq(1, 1000, 25)
x2 <- rnorm(40, mean = 1, sd = 0.25)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
bardf <- data.frame(x = c(150,500,750), 
                    height = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.2), 
                    width = c(50,70,90))
p <- ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(data = bardf, aes(x,height, width = width), fill = "white", stat = "identity") +
    geom_line(data = df, aes(x1,x2))

print(p)
gglocator()
```

And this is the plot:
[image: to find: area between barplot and under the curve]

To find: area between barplot and under the curve (please ignore the red circle). 
Anybody have any idea how to proceed with this challenge. I found couple of questions in SO regarding calculating area but most of them were for ROC or just about shading the region. Any suggestions/ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't try to do this within ggplot itself; while it may be possible, it's a package built for graphing, not calculating. Instead, just use `integrate`, e.g. `integrate(approxfun(df$x1, df$x2), 125, 175)`

Comment: ...and if the bar can be lower than the line, wrap `approxfun` in another function that calls `pmin` with the appropriate value.

Comment: @alistaire Thank you for the reply. I thought of using integrate function. But my problem, like this plot, may have multiple peaks or lows in between   the barplot boundaries. So I was wondering whether there is a function to provide multiple points rather than the upper and lower limit for interpolation and then I can use integration on it. So do you know any other alternate function to approxfun() which allow this?

Comment: Wait, do you want the area in the bars under the line, or the area outside of the bars under the line?

Comment: @alistaire Area inside the bar and under the line.

Comment: Then the solution below with `integrate`, `approxfun`, and `pmin` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `approxfun` to build a function that will interpolate points, you can use `integrate` to calculate the area. If the bar can be lower than the line, `pmin` can return the lower of the heights:

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)    # returns a line partially higher than a bar

df <- data.frame(x1 = seq(1, 1000, 25), 
                 x2 = rnorm(40, mean = 1, sd = 0.25))
bardf <- data.frame(x = c(150,500,750), 
                    height = c(1.4, 1.4,1.2), 
                    width = c(50,70,90))

ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = bardf, aes(x, height, width = width), fill = "white") +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x1, x2))
```

[image]

```r
# iterate in parallel over bardf to calculate all areas at once
mapply(function(x, h, w){
    integrate(function(v){pmin(approxfun(df$x1, df$x2)(v), h)}, 
              lower = x - .5 * w, 
              upper = x + .5 * w
    )$value}, 
    bardf$x, bardf$height, bardf$width)
#> [1] 52.40707 83.28773 98.38771
```

Comment: Thank you!! Looks like that'll do the job!

Comment: One more question, Is there anyway I can shade that calculated area in this plot?

Comment: You could probably do it with `geom_area`, but you may have to rearrange your data pretty considerably to make it work.

Comment: Ok I'll work that out. Thank you very much for your help :)